# How to use loop to define self with similar names?

Tags: python

I have many `self` definations in a class. Their names look very similar but with small differences.

My Question: how to use loop to define all the `self`s? So that I dont have to write all the similar lines.

Code:

```
class types():
    def __init__(self):
        self.type_1 = "a"
        self.type_2 = "a"
        self.type_3 = "a"
        self.type_4 = "a"
        self.type_5 = "a"
        self.type_6 = "a"
        self.type_7 = "a"
        ... many of the similar...
        self.type_nn = "a"
        # Question: Is it possible to use loop to define all the self?
```

This question might be duplicated but I cant find the answer. Thanks!

**EDIT:** Sorry for the hush post. I forgot something.
I want to write something like `self.type_10` in my later function. That means there should be a `self.type_10` defination in the `__init__`
Thank you!

Comment: It is possible, but just use a list

Comment: Why do you "want" to write `self.type_10` and not `self.type[10]`? This all violates the DRY principle.

Comment: You'll be using all of these variables in the code, so its not that big a deal to write them one more time in the initializer. As noted, it may be better to just have a list of types or something like that. That depends on how you use the data later. Sine we don't know that, its just speculation.

Answer (score 1):

You don't declare N variables. This violates the DRY (don't repeat yourself) principle of clean code. Use a list or a dictionary instead.

```
class types():
    def __init__(self):
        self.types = ["a", "a", ... "a"]
```

and later write a `for` loop.

```
for type in self.types:
    print(type)
```

Instead of `self.type_10` you can access the item by `self.types[9]`. You could also insert an empty item in the beginning and then access by `self.types[10]`, but again, nobody would do that. Indexing always begins at 0.

---

If you really really can't change it, you can access the properties via `vars()`:

```
class types():
    def __init__(self):
        self.type_1 = "a"
        self.type_2 = "a"
        self.type_3 = "a"
        self.type_4 = "a"
        self.type_5 = "a"
        self.type_6 = "a"
        self.type_7 = "a"

    def listall(self):
        for name, attr in vars(self).items():
            if name.startswith("type_"):
                print(name, attr)

t = types()
t.listall()
```

But be prepared that any readers of your code may come and beat you for that :-)

Comment: Well, it is *possible* just it seems like terrible design

Comment: or a dictionary if the types names are relevant to something

Comment: If you are going to do this, use `vars(self)` not dir. For `name, attribute in vars(self).items(): ...`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: ok, learned something new. Looks much cleaner